# Is there a 'biggg' in Latex/Lyx environment?

Tags: brackets

I'm using Lyx editor and have added the `amsmath` environment. And in the editor, I can input the `\biggg{` to show a slightly bigger `{` than the `\bigg{`. But it has errors when compiling the document. So, is there a bigger `{` than the `\bigg{` or `\Bigg{`?

For example, in the following equation, I want the pair `{}` should be one level larger than the pair `[]` for better view. The `{}` for the equation is using `\Bigg{` and `\Bigg}`.

[image: equation]

Comment: Just to check: are you aware of \left and \right?

Comment: Hi, @MartinArgerami, I've tried `\left{` or `\left\{`, but neither did the work well. I've add the `amsmath` package in the preamble. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't make larger braces in the example you posted, but rather smaller brackets. However, you can easily extend the predefined sizes of `amsmath`. The `latex.ltx` format defines

```
\def\bigl{\mathopen\big}
\def\bigm{\mathrel\big}
\def\bigr{\mathclose\big}
\def\Bigl{\mathopen\Big}
\def\Bigm{\mathrel\Big}
\def\Bigr{\mathclose\Big}
\def\biggl{\mathopen\bigg}
\def\biggm{\mathrel\bigg}
\def\biggr{\mathclose\bigg}
\def\Biggl{\mathopen\Bigg}
\def\Biggm{\mathrel\Bigg}
\def\Biggr{\mathclose\Bigg}
```

and the original definition of `\big` & Co. is overwritten by `amsmath`, which replaces them by

```
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
\renewcommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\renewcommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
\renewcommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
```

Here `\bBigg@` is the macro which actually does the scaling job: it takes an argument (the height in a length called `\big@size`). So you can use the following lines

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\biggg}{\bBigg@\thr@@}
\newcommand{\Biggg}{\bBigg@{3.5}}
\def\bigggl{\mathopen\biggg}
\def\bigggm{\mathrel\biggg}
\def\bigggr{\mathclose\biggg}
\def\Bigggl{\mathopen\Biggg}
\def\Bigggm{\mathrel\Biggg}
\def\Bigggr{\mathclose\Biggg}
\makeatother
```